# How to turn dynamic DOM element into Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have the following HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="condition_value_1">
<span class="click_me">Click Me</span>
```

I am replacing the `#condition_value_1` element with a SELECT type as follow and trying to turn the recently SELECT into a Select2:

```
$(function() {
  $('.click_me').click(function(ev) {
    var condition_value_1 = $('#condition_value_1');
    var select_html = '<select name="condition_value_1" id="condition_value_1"></select>';
    condition_value_1.replaceWith(select_html);

    $('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '#condition_value_1', function() {
      $(this).select2({
        placeholder: 'Start typing ...',
        tags: true
      });
    });
  });
});
```

But is not working since the element keep as a normal HTML Select type and doesn't turn into a Select2. Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/o1dx3euu/1/) for you to play with. I am using jQuery 1.12.4 and Select 4.0.3.

How do I turn a dynamic element into a Select2 element? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work for me if not using `DOMNodeInserted` event binding.

It's fair to assume the element has been added to the DOM when the `replaceWith()` method is called.

[JS Fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/o1dx3euu/2/)

```
$(function() {
  $('.click_me').click(function(ev) {
    var condition_value_1 = $('#condition_value_1');
    var select_html = '<select name="condition_value_1" id="condition_value_1"></select>';
    condition_value_1.replaceWith(select_html);

    $('#condition_value_1').select2({
        placeholder: 'Start typing ...',
        tags: true
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: I have tried to chain them (https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/o1dx3euu/3/) (as always overthinking easy stuff) and doesn't work for me that's why I try to use another path but yes, yours works! Thx